# Do I have to stop the Google Analytics tracker in applicationWillTerminate? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics in my app, and while I believe I've carefully followed the getting started guides and screen tracking manuals, I don't see anywhere that I should stop the tracker when the app goes to the background or terminates. I can assume that maybe I don't have to, but I don't want to assume. So, should I? Or does Google Analytics automatically stop when the app goes to the background/terminates? (I also can't find documentation that says so.)

I also ask this because I see from `GAITracker.h` that there's a method called `close`. Its description is as follows:

> Close the tracker. This will mark it as closed and remove it from the
>   list of trackers accessible through [GAI trackerWithTrackingId:], thus
>   decrementing its reference count (and causing it to be dealloced
>   unless it has been retained by the application). Once this method has
>   been called, it is an error to call any of the tracking methods, and
>   they will not result in the generation of any tracking information to
>   be submitted to Google Analytics.

And since, if I understand correctly, `close` effectively removes the tracker from memory, does simply calling `[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingID:@"MY-TRACKING-ID"]` create a new one which I can use when the app is re-launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to stop Google analytics tracker for iOS. 
Google had added `close method` in `iOS SDK version 2.0beta1(May 25, 2012)`. But, they had not provided any document or tutorial to use this till date. I have used Google analytics in my two apps to track app installation, screen most visited and some events also. I didn't close(or stop) the tracker anywhere in the app and I guess it's not necessary till now.

We add the following code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-YOUR-TRACKING-ID"];
```

The above line creates a new tracker instance everytime as the app launches. 
So, I don't think it would be necessary to stop(or close) the tracker as the app terminates.

Comment: In that case, allow me to add: I didn't call that line in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but it my first view controller's `viewWillAppear` instead. Google's docs says that `trackerWithTrackingId:` *create(s) or retrieve(s) a GAITracker implementation with the specified tracking ID. **If the tracker for the specified tracking ID does not already exist, then it will be created and returned;** otherwise, the existing tracker will be returned.*